# Rails WHERE method in the context of SCOPE for like ? syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, where-clause

I fail to find the right syntax for a WHERE method in the context of a SCOPE. My classified MODEL has several SCOPE that works well to filter classifieds by category or area:

```
#in the model  
scope :filter_by_category, -> (category) {where category: category}
scope :filter_by_area, -> (area) {where area: area}
```

I want to do a more advanced SCOPE filter to search for classifieds' Titles **containing a specific string**. Outside of SCOPE I would generally retrieve the data with:

```
Classified.where("title like ?", "%title%")
```

But in the context a SCOPE, I do not manage to find the right syntax and keep getting some errors (unexpected ->, expecting `end' scope [...]). I tried the following:

```
scope :filter_by_title -> (title) { where ("title like ?","%title%")}
scope :filter_by_title -> (title) { where ("like ?","%title%")}
```

Both give me syntax error. Could anyone help me find the right syntax please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problems:

1. The lambda is an argument to `scope` to you need a comma after the symbol:

   ```
    scope :filter_by_title, -> ...
    # --------------------^
   ```
2. Whitespace matters in Ruby so `f (x, y)` and `f(x, y)` are different things. The parentheses in `f (x, y)` are expression grouping parentheses whereas in `f(x, y)` they're method calling parentheses. So `f (x, y)` is a syntax error because `x, y` isn't an expression. Remove the stray space:

   ```
   scope :filter_by_title, ->(title) { where('title like ?', ...
   # ---------------------------------------^ No more space here
   ```
3. You want to use string interpolation to expand the `title` argument to the scope:

   ```
   scope :filter_by_title, ->(title) { where('title like ?', "%#{title}%") }
   # ----------------------------------------------------------^^-----^ Interpolation
   ```